# design login controller logic using Yii

Tags: php, controller, yii

I am thinking about a login interface. There is a drop down list on that login interface to select one of several user types. The 'log in' button is calling an action to validate the login data in the login controller.

Now, if the login data for user type A is valid, I want to call controllerA. If login data for user type B is valid, I want to call controllerB.

But I know that calling a controller from another controller is not wise.

Then, is there another idea on how to do this login mechanism?

Obviously I can divide the login interface into several parts, each part for each user type.

Answer (score 0):

may this will help you http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/89/module-based-login/

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Actually I have an idea before you post your answer.
The idea was I have a login module (a CController object). Login information is validated in this login module. If a login is valid then the module assemble a respond page/view and a special JavaScript is embedded in that respond. On the browser, that JavaScript redirects the user to one of several other controllers. The user's type controls which controllers to load next.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in your regular Login action in your Site controller, you could look at the dropdown POST, and with some simple logic validate the user credentials against the right Module/DB tables pretty easily? And just redirect to correct module's after-login url?